# Geração de números aleatórios em uma função é sempre igual - C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int aleatorio(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % 10 + 1;
}

main(){
    int numero1 = aleatorio();
    int numero2 = aleatorio();
    printf("%d %d",numero1, numero2);
}
```

Eu tenho um projeto pra fazer e nele vou usar uma função que gera números aleatórios, então decidi ir fazendo testes nela e a função sempre retorna o mesmo número, mesmo que eu tenha colocado a semente dentro do rand(). Mesmo que a semente tenha sido colocada dentro de uma função, o número gerado não deveria ser diferente já como cada vez que eu chamo ela uma nova semente é colocada.
Gostaria que me ajudassem.

Comment: basicamente pelo fato de você fazer o srand duas vezes com o mesmo valor. Faça o srand uma vez só, senão você reseta o seed a cada chamada da função (ou seja, duas chamadas no mesmo time() vão sempre resultar o mesmo valor.

Comment: Retire  `srand(time(NULL));`de sua função. Ele deve ser executado uma única vez no início do programa e não a cada chamada da função `aleatorio`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código chama a função `aleatorio()` duas veze em seguida. Dentro dessa função tem um `srand`, que serve para inicializar a sequência de números aleatórios (a "semente", ou "*seed*").

Ocorre que muito provavelmente, a maior parte das vezes que chamar a função em seguida, o `time()` retornará o mesmo valor nas duas chamadas, efetivamente "resetando" a sequência para começar sempre do mesmo número.

Idealmente você só faz um `srand(time())` uma vez no código, o que resolve esse e outros eventuais problemas que podem originar de mudar o *seed* com frequência.

Veja como fica o código depois de modificado para usar o `srand` uma vez só:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int aleatorio(){
    return rand() % 10 + 1;
}

main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numero1 = aleatorio();
    int numero2 = aleatorio();
    printf("%d %d",numero1, numero2);
}
```

Veja funcionando no IDEONE:

https://ideone.com/xzCdF2

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int aleatorio(){
    return rand() % 10 + 1;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numero1 = aleatorio();
    int numero2 = aleatorio();
    printf("%d %d",numero1, numero2);
    return 0;
}
```

Coloque a seed dentro do main.